# Google SSO error app_not_configured_for_user

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace

I have a company website that is using Google GSuite SSO to authenticate users. The site is registered as a SAML app within GSuite.

The login works fine when I use my company Google credentials, but when I try using me personal gmail account credentials I get an unfriendly "app_not_configured_for_user" error.

Does anyone know why?  My expectation was a friendly error. Something along the lines of "Sorry, you don't have access to this app"

Answer (score 0):

If you see the message “You need a Google Cloud account to login,” you might be trying to access a service that's being managed or blocked by an organization, like your work or school.

Basic Google account can't access G Suite. (e.g: example@gmail.com)

A Google Cloud account is an account that's set up through your work or school, a club, or maybe family or friends. It's also sometimes called a G Suite account.

For more details, you can check out: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6375836?hl=en

Cheers.

Comment: Yes, i understand that.  My question was about why google is showing an unfriendly error like this when I was expecting a friendly error, as this is hardly an edge case.  It felt like there is a bug somewhere

Comment: Did you configure the callback url in Google SAML App panel?
you need to set URL ACS in the google SAML App form to your callback url (yourdomain.com/auth/saml/callback by default).

Comment: Yeah I did set that.  Do you know if the unfriendly error message is the expected message in this scenario?  I'm not sure if there is a friendly error msg at all.  Maybe this is just how Google SSO works

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem several times setting up SSO with a web application. Each time, it takes quite long but eventually it works.

What I discovered is that, the Google configuration "Enable for everyone" seems to take a while to propagate. If I disable it for everyone and then enable it again, suddenly the SSO configuration starts working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just needed to remove the cookies of the webpage. Just for the page tat shows the error. But as it is a quite generic error, it depends ;)